# Why when changing an object alpha color to 0 at the end the object is blinking for a millisecond?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In general the teleporting is working but on the first teleporter when the alpha is change to 0 just at the end before the object disappear the object blink for a millisecond and you see for a millisecond the whole object again then the object disappear and move to the second teleporter.

The idea is that it will disappear when changing the alpha to 0 and will change back to 1 in the second teleporter. Not sure why it's blinking at the end of the changing to 0.

I checked now again and for some reason it's doing the code in the Update twice instead once. Even if setting teleported to false for some reason it's doing everything twice in a row.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> teleporters = new List<GameObject>();
    public GameObject objectToTeleportMaterial;
    public float fadeDuration = 5;
    public float fadeInTargetOpacity = 0;
    public float fadeOutTargetOpacity = 1;

    private List<Vector3> teleportersPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    private bool teleported = false;
    private Material material;
    private GameObject myother;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        teleporters.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Teleporter"));

        if (teleporters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (GameObject teleporter in teleporters)
            {
                teleportersPositions.Add(teleporter.transform.position);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        teleported = false;
        myother = other.gameObject;
        material = objectToTeleportMaterial.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        Teleport(material, fadeInTargetOpacity, fadeDuration);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (teleported == true)
        {
            myother.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().enabled = false;
            myother.GetComponent<AgentControl>().enabled = false;
            myother.transform.position = teleporters[0].transform.position;
            Teleport(material, fadeOutTargetOpacity, fadeDuration);
            teleported = false;
        }
    }

    private void Teleport(Material material, float fadeTargetOpacity, float fadeDuration)
    {
        MaterialExtensions.ToFadeMode(material);
        StartCoroutine(FadeTo(material, fadeTargetOpacity, fadeDuration));
    }

    // Define an enumerator to perform our fading.
    // Pass it the material to fade, the opacity to fade to (0 = transparent, 1 = opaque),
    // and the number of seconds to fade over.
    IEnumerator FadeTo(Material material, float targetOpacity, float duration)
    {

        // Cache the current color of the material, and its initiql opacity.
        Color color = material.color;
        float startOpacity = color.a;

        // Track how many seconds we've been fading.
        float t = 0;

        while (t < duration)
        {
            // Step the fade forward one frame.
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            // Turn the time into an interpolation factor between 0 and 1.
            float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

            // Blend to the corresponding opacity between start & target.
            color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

            // Apply the resulting color to the material.
            material.color = color;

            // Wait one frame, and repeat.
            yield return null;
        }

        if (targetOpacity == 1)
        {
            myother.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().enabled = true;
            myother.GetComponent<AgentControl>().enabled = true;
        }

        if (targetOpacity == 0)
        {
            teleported = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use DOTween for tweening the alpha to 0 or to target value.
Maybe Clamp ruining your alpha.
All you need is install DOTween from Asset store, attach to your code with

```
using DG.Tweening;
```

And tween the alpha with `material.DOFade(*targetAlpha*, *durationOfTween*);`